# Should I use OrderByDescending twice in LINQ?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a products table like this:-

```
ProductID     ProductName     Price
   1            Milk           10
   2            Banana         20
   3            Apple          15
   1            Grapes         12
   2            Banana         25
   1             Milk          8
```

I want to find the products who have maximum price for each productId.

Sample Output:-

```
    ProductID     ProductName     Price
       1            Grapes          12
       2            Banana         25
       3            Apple          15
```

I have tried this query:-

```
List<Product> groups = products
    .GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
    .Select(p => new Product
        {
            ProductId = p.Key,
            Name = p.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).First().Name,
            Price = p.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).First().Price,
        })
    .ToList();
```

This query is working fine, but my question is should i use `OrderByDescending` twice? I mean since i just want single item based on 1 property and suppose there are multiple other properties, so do i need to use same logic again and again?

**Edit:**
Pardon me forgot to mention, Please Assume ProductName can be different, Please check updated tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't have to, you can just select `First()`:

```
new Product
{
    ProductId = p.Key,
    Name = p.First().Name,
    Bar = p.First().Bar,
    Price = p.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).First().Price,
}
```

This of course assumes all products with a given `ProductId` have the same `Name` and `Bar`.

If this isn't the case and you want to map all properties from the selected entity, create a code block in your `Select()`:

```
.Select(p => 
{   
    var havingHighestPrice = p.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).First()

    return new Product
    {
      ProductId = p.Key,
      Name = havingHighestPrice.Name,
      Bar = havingHighestPrice.Bar,
      Price = havingHighestPrice.Price,
    }
})
```

Comment: will it return same product Name which price we are picking?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks for reply, but what if productNames are different? I have updated my question.

Comment: @Coder and I had already updated my answer, see second code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq query syntax to store local variables:

```
var groups = from p in products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
             let first = p.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).First()
             select new Product
             {
                 ProductId = p.Key,
                 Name = first.Name,
                 Price = first.Price,
             };
```

What's important is that it's safe to use in Entity Framework queries.